# Extracting first Google result URL - "runtime error '424': object required"

Tags: excel, vba

I've had success using the VBA posted by @Dorian below (including the required change to "Microsoft Internet Controls"), but after running it a couple of times, I start getting

> "Run-time error '424': Object required".

I've not made any changes to the Excel sheet or the code.  Sometimes I just restart my computer and it will work again a few times, but then the problem returns.  The excel sheet is a simple column of terms starting at cell A2.  Any help would be appreciated (and I apologize in advance if I've left something important out of my question).

Thanks.

From @Dorian post:

Please Note that you will need to add référence :

Tools --> References --> Microsoft Internet Controls

```
Option Explicit
Sub tryme()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 2 To lastrow
        ie.Visible = False
        ie.navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1)
        While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

       Cells(i, 2).Value = ie.document.querySelector("#search div.r [href*=http]").href

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Sound more like your experiencing a throttle on queries to the website. most websites have that to prevent DDOS attacks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I would have thought the same, but it happens even on some fairly small lists (e.g. 50 or 60), but at times will run properly on lists of 500+.  I know it's likely not random, but I've yet to figure out the pattern as to when it happens.